# Method in C# that takes string as input and returns integer

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and would like to know a basic question. I want to define a method in C# that takes following input as string:
C1
C2
C3
C4
.....C500

When C1 or C2 is input, I want my output as 1. Whenever C3 or C4 is input, output should be 2. Similarly for C5 or C6, the output should be 3 and so on... Is there a better way other than if/else or switch case.

```
public int GetInt(string input)
{
int x;
return x;
}
```

Switch case or If else only makes sense if I have limited string values. However, i have almost 500 or even more strings that can be used as input

Comment: int x= int.Parse(input);

Comment: `if (input == "C1" || input == "C2") { .... }`

Comment: @jdweng `int.Parse("C4")`?

Comment: try to formulate your task in a few sentences. So when input is `"C1" or `"C2"`, `1` should be returned, otherwise `2`. You need some `if/else`-statament for that.

Comment: ignore the first character : int x= int.Parse(input.Substring(1));

Comment: Please read the question again. i modified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work without hundreds of `if`s:

```
public int GetInt(string input)
{
    if(!Regex.Match(input, "C[0-9]+"))
    {
        throw new FormatException("invalid input string");
    }

    string sub = input.Substring(1);
    int i = int.Parse(sub);
    return i / 2;
}
```

First, we check with a regular expression, whether the input has the correct format. Then we create a substring starting at the second char. This will omit the 'C'. We parse this string as an integer, divide it by two and return it.

Answer (score 1):

if the string input are static, and they are only few option why don't you use switch statement

```
switch(input)
{
  case "C1": return x; 

  // and so on 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public int GetInt(string input)
    {
        switch (input)
        {
            case "C1":
                return 1;
            case "C2":
                return 1;
            case "C3":
                return 2;
            case "C4":
                return 2;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
```

This will give you exactly what you are looking for, just replace the "C1", "C2", etc with the string values you are checking for and change the default if all four cases aren't found, I returned 0 but you could throw an exception or check for zero and handle accordingly.

Comment: Please read my question again. I have modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming inputs can only be C1,C2,C3, or C4, it's pretty straight foward, check if the inputs are the ones that should output 1, output 1 in that case, and output 2 in any other case. But if you need to deal with more than 2 output possibilities, use a `switch`

```
public int GetInt(string input)
{
    if(input == "C1" || input == "C2")
    {
       return 1;
    }
    else
    {
       return 2;
    }
}
```